# update action_button_confirm button in openerp

Tags: odoo

I have sale order data ,when i confirm order i have no data from sale order form ...what should i do?...i think, i need update to this

```
def action_button_confirm(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        assert len(ids) == 1, 'This option should only be used for a single id at a time.'
        wf_service = netsvc.LocalService('workflow')
        wf_service.trg_validate(uid, 'sale.order', ids[0], 'order_confirm', cr)

        # redisplay the record as a sales order
        view_ref = self.pool.get('ir.model.data').get_object_reference(cr, uid, 'sale', 'view_order_form')
        view_id = view_ref and view_ref[1] or False,
        return {
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'name': _('Sales Order'),
            'res_model': 'sale.order',
            'res_id': ids[0],
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'view_id': view_id,
            'target': 'current',
            'nodestroy': True,
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When we confirm the sale order following process are done in background,

- in Warehouse => Scheduler => Procurement Exception, will generate procurement with that Sale Order
- in Warehouse => Receive/Deliver By Orders => Delivery Orders, will generate delivery order of that Sale Order
- in Warehouse => Receive/Deliver Products => Deliver Products, it will show how to deliver product to that Sale Order Customer

Hope this will help you